# AndEngine PhysicsExample

Tags: java, android, andengine, physics, game-development

So, I was studying the AndEngine PhysicsExample code. I was wondering what is the meaning of this method (http://pastebin.com/Day2hciB):

```
private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
        this.mFaceCount++;
        Debug.d("Faces: " + this.mFaceCount);

        final AnimatedSprite face;
        final Body body;

        if(this.mFaceCount % 4 == 0) {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        } else if (this.mFaceCount % 4 == 1) {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        } else if (this.mFaceCount % 4 == 2) {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mTriangleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsExample.createTriangleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        } else {
            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mHexagonFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            body = PhysicsExample.createHexagonBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        }

        face.animate(200);

        this.mScene.attachChild(face);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
    }
```

Comment: Please put the code here and not on a third party site and also explain what you do not understand see the [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

```
private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
            this.mFaceCount++;
            Debug.d("Faces: " + this.mFaceCount);

            final AnimatedSprite face;
            final Body body;

            if(this.mFaceCount % 4 == 0) {
                    face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            } else if (this.mFaceCount % 4 == 1) {
                    face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            } else if (this.mFaceCount % 4 == 2) {
                    face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mTriangleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    body = PhysicsExample.createTriangleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            } else {
                    face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mHexagonFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    body = PhysicsExample.createHexagonBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            }

            face.animate(200);

            this.mScene.attachChild(face);
            this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
    }
```

What this code does is set a body to a sprite depending on its shape. mFaceCount adds 1 to itself each time a face is added. What this line does:

```
if(this.mFaceCount % 4 == 0)
```

is checks to see if the remainder when divided by 4 is equal to 0 (and 1, 2, 3 for the others). All this does is tell it which sprite to add to the scene. You'll notice that you first add a square, then a circle, then a triangle, then a hexagon.

The real code is in these lines here:

```
face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
```

This creates a sprite called face and attaches a box body to it. The next one attaches a circle. Now you'll notice the next two are different. They say PhysicsExample.create instead of PhysicsFactory.create. PhysicsExample is the activity, so they are calling a method within PhysicsExample instead of from PhysicsFactory. createTriangleBody actually calls this method (later on in the code):

```
private static Body createTriangleBody(final PhysicsWorld pPhysicsWorld, final IAreaShape pAreaShape, final BodyType pBodyType, final FixtureDef pFixtureDef) {
    /* Remember that the vertices are relative to the center-coordinates of the Shape. */
    final float halfWidth = pAreaShape.getWidthScaled() * 0.5f / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;
    final float halfHeight = pAreaShape.getHeightScaled() * 0.5f / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;

    final float top = -halfHeight;
    final float bottom = halfHeight;
    final float left = -halfHeight;
    final float centerX = 0;
    final float right = halfWidth;

    final Vector2[] vertices = {
            new Vector2(centerX, top),
            new Vector2(right, bottom),
            new Vector2(left, bottom)
    };

    return PhysicsFactory.createPolygonBody(pPhysicsWorld, pAreaShape, vertices, pBodyType, pFixtureDef);
}
```

This creates a triangle around the sprite (don't ask me how. I don't understand the math he used here, but I copied it exactly and it works for roughly equilateral triangle. The whole vertices thing would take some playing. And I don't get vectors!!). The createHexagonMethod does the same thing, just with a hexagon. Answer your question I hope? Let me know if I left anything out.